# Center of a Ring Notation (or lack of)

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Quick question that I did not see on line or in the book I'm working out of (Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote).  There is an example that defines the center of a ring $R$ as
$$\{z\in R\mid zr=rz, \ \forall r\in R\}$$

It's a silly notation question, but since the center of a group has its notation as $Z(G)$, why don't the authors give the notation for the center of a ring as $Z(R)$?

Comment: Might be self evident from previous definitions of center in groups.